# Explanation for combination of cycle drop and take in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to understand the implementation of rotating a sequence to which the answer i find in git hub is below

```
(fn [n coll]
  (take (count coll) (drop (mod n (count coll)) (cycle coll))))
```

Could you please explain what is exacty happening here

```
(take 6 (drop 1 (cycle ["a" "b" "c"])))
("b" "c" "a" "b" "c" "a")
```

How is this being produced

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation of `cycle`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cycle):

> Returns a lazy (infinite!) sequence of repetitions of the items in coll.

So in your example:

```
(cycle ["a" "b" "c"])
;; => ["a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c" ...]
```

(toward infinity and beyond)

To cut down an infinite sequence, you have to use `take` which takes the first `n` element of a sequence. So:

```
(take 6 (cycle ["a" "b" "c"]))
;; => ["a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c"]
```

In your example, just before calling `take`, you use `drop` which left out the first `n` element of a sequence. So:

```
(drop 1 (cycle ["a" "b" "c"]))
;; => ["b" "c" "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c" ...]
(take 6 (drop 1 (cycle ["a" "b" "c"])))
;; => ["b" "c" "a" "b" "c" "a"]
```

You can learn more about lazy sequences from [this chapter of "Clojure from the Brave and True"](https://www.braveclojure.com/core-functions-in-depth/).

Comment: thanks alot @rozar , could you also redirect me towards a mentor for clojure. I want to learn.

Comment: I don't have a mentor to recommend you, sorry. But still if you want to learn, you can find a lot of materials there:
https://notamonadtutorial.com/how-to-earn-your-clojure-white-belt-7e7db68a71e5

Comment: There's also the clojurians Slack chat, which includes a Beginners channel: http://clojurians.net/